# Setting custom header values on page reload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to reload my page with JavaScript

```
window.location='http://example.com'
```

However, I also want to send custom headers. I learned that this is only possible in XHR, but XHR doesn't load the page. Is there a way I can change the windows location while sending a custom header?

Comment: You can't set custom headers with window.location. What are you trying to set?

Comment: I'm trying to set my user agent to something else

Comment: JavaScript is not going to do it.

Comment: Is this just for you or you expecting all users to have this ability?

Comment: It's a JS file just for my personal use.

Comment: Chrome has it built into the developer tools

Comment: Firefox has the extension "UserAgentSwitcher" and others for that.